# Difference between permissions 700 and 070

Tags: debian, permissions, users, group, container

in debain if a owner is not given access to a directory but the group which includes the owner has access to the directory will the owner still be able to access the directory?

A scenario:

If a user named nginx who has id 101 and group nginx with id 101 is present in nginx container. Then same user and group with id 101 has been created in app container. Then the www.conf file located at /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/ is modified and now user = nginx and group = nginx.
Now, if I set the permission of everything in app container at /var/www/html to 700 I am able to access it from my browser at localhost:8080 mapped to port 80 of the container.
But if I change the permission of the /var/www/html/ contents to 070 and still try to access it from the same nginx container which is nginx with id 101, will it work? Because the 070 permission allow the group nginx to access the php-fpm service but not the owner which is user nginx with id 101

Comment: Why not test it and see?